# Is it possible to update FileList?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
<input type="file" id="f" name="f" onchange="c()" multiple />
```

Every time the user selects a file(s), I build a list of all the selected files by pushing each element of `f.files` to an array:

```
var Files = [];
function c() {
  for (var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++) {
    Files.push(this.files[i]);
  };
}
```

At form submit, `f.files` contains only the item(s) from the last select action, so I will need to update `f.files` with the list of `FileList` items I have accumulated:

```
const upload=document.getElementById("f");
upload.files = files;
```

But the second line gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'.

It is not happy that I am assigning it an array. How can I construct a `FileList` object from the list of `FileList` elements I have earlier collected?

Side question: I thought Javascript uses dynamic types. Why is it complaining about the wrong type here?

Comment: I can't find a reference, but my strong suspicion is that `File` objects must be part of an active `FileList` associated with an `<input>` element or a drag-and-drop target.

Comment: Here someone answered similar question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38449440/javascript-create-file-list-object-from-list-of-files

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's like you said

> Failed to set the 'files' property on 'HTMLInputElement': The provided value is not of type 'FileList'.

you can only set the files with a FileList instance, unfortunately the FileList is not constructible or changeable, but there is a way to get one in a round about way

```js
/** @params {File[]} files - Array of files to add to the FileList */
function fileListFrom (files) {
  const b = new ClipboardEvent("").clipboardData || new DataTransfer()
  for (const file of files) b.items.add(file)
  return b.files
}

const fileList = fileListFrom([
  new File(['content'], 'sample1.txt'),
  new File(['abc'], 'sample2.txt')
])

fileInput.onchange = console.log
fileInput.files = fileList

console.log(fileInput.files)
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple />
```

EDIT: Setting `input.files` *might* trigger a change event. (seems to have been [fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792336) now) so you might want to toggle the change event listener on and off. (But might not have to anymore. Included a change listener to the demo)

Comment: As a side note, this does not work on iOS Safari. I've yet to solve.

Comment: This doesn't work on test, ex. node complain `ClipboardEvent` not defined.

Comment: @windmaomao then you are probably using a old browser that don't have the global ClipboardEvent what you want to do in this case is to first check if ClipboardEvent exist and if not use the DataTransfer instead.

Comment: According to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133001, "user interaction is necessary for clipboard access".

Comment: For me it worked using `fileInput.prop('files', new FileListItems(files))` instead of `fileInput.files = new FileListItems(files)`

Comment: FileListItems is a method, not object. Right?

Comment: FileListItems is a function that return a [FileList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) class of Files

Answer (score 99):

You can't modify a Filelist, but you can create a new one using a DataTransfer object, and if you wish you can copy your data into it to create a duplicate with the specific change you want to make.

```
let list = new DataTransfer();
let file = new File(["content"], "filename.jpg");
list.items.add(file);

let myFileList = list.files;
```

You can then set it as the file attribute of the DOM node:

```
fileInput.files = myFileList;
```

If you wished, you could iterate over your old FileList, copying files to the new one.

Comment: DataTransfer() dosn't support iOS

Comment: Alsoo `.items` on `DataTransfer()` is not supported in IE11

Comment: `DataTransfer()` not supported in safari as well. Safari is becoming like IE.

Comment: Safari on both Mac and ios now supports `DataTransfer()`!!!
https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_datatransfer_datatransfer

It works since April, 2021

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to modify `FileList`, but you can create a `new DataTransfer` object, add one or multiple files to `dataTransfer.items` and assign it to `input.files`. Here's my code example with drag&drop functionality:

```
const imageUploadLabel = document.getElementById('image-upload-label')
const imageUploadInput = document.getElementById('image-upload-input')

['dragenter', 'dragover', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  imageUploadLabel.addEventListener(eventName, event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
  })
})

['dragenter', 'dragover'].forEach(eventName => {
  imageUploadLabel.addEventListener(eventName, () => {
    imageUploadLabel.classList.add('highlight')
  })
})

['dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(eventName => {
  imageUploadLabel.addEventListener(eventName, () => {
    imageUploadLabel.classList.remove('highlight')
  })
})

let dataTransfer = new DataTransfer()

imageUploadLabel.addEventListener('drop', event => {
  uploadFiles(event.dataTransfer.files)
})

imageUploadInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  uploadFiles(imageUploadInput.files)
})

function uploadFiles(files) {
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    dataTransfer.items.add(files[i])
  }

  imageUploadInput.files = dataTransfer.files
  console.log(imageUploadInput.files)
}
```