# How to detect that different File objects are referring to the same file?

Tags: javascript

```
<input id='f' name='f' multiple />
```

I am allowing the user to select multiple files (from different folders) for upload. I build the list of selected files as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52078853/936293). Basically the list of selected files is maintained outside of the `INPUT` control and stuffed back into `f.files` at submit time.

The list of selected files is built from the `File` object in the array `f.files` each time the user selects a file(s).

So far, this works well, except that I am unable to detect duplicate files selected. `f.files` contains only the file name and not the full path.

I applied `URL.createObjectURL` on the `File` object but each time it is a different url, even with the same file.

(In Chrome, the upload control will not fire the `change` event if the same file was selected in succession. But this isn't sufficient for me, as the user can select file A, then file B, and then file A again.)

How do I identify duplicate files from the `File` object?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have. For example the `onChange` function etc.

Comment: Possible workaround: Check file name / size / lastModified properties and compare them to identify as possible duplicate. Comparing BLOB objects (URL.createObjectURL) as an additional filter you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to read the contents of each file.

Then you can compare the file contents along with the other properties of each file, including [`File.lastModified`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModified), [`File.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name), [`File.size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/size), and [`File.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/type) to determine if the file is a duplicate.

**Full Example:**

```js
const file_input = document.getElementById( 'f' );

file_input.addEventListener( 'change', () =>
{
    const file_compare = [];
    
    Array.from( file_input.files ).forEach( file =>
    {
        const file_reader = new FileReader();
        
        file_reader.readAsDataURL( file );
        
        file_reader.addEventListener( 'load', () =>
        {
            const file_exists = file_compare.find( existing_file =>
                
                   existing_file.lastModified === file.lastModified
                && existing_file.name         === file.name
                && existing_file.size         === file.size
                && existing_file.type         === file.type
                && existing_file.content      === file_reader.result
                
            ) !== undefined;
            
            if ( file_exists )
            {
                console.log( 'Error:', file.name, 'is a duplicate file.' );
            }
            
            else
            {
                file_compare.push(
                {
                    'lastModified' : file.lastModified,
                    'name'         : file.name,
                    'size'         : file.size,
                    'type'         : file.type,
                    'content'      : file_reader.result
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<input id="f" name="f" type="file" multiple />
```

> **Note:** If you are dealing with very large files, you can limit the comparisons to `File.lastModified`, `File.name`, `File.size`, and `File.type` as a performance enhancer.

Comment: Do the size & fileModified checks before going through the reader. There is **very** little chance that you'll get the same on two different files, and loading every file as dataURL will blow your Memory if you are dealing with gigs of data.