# Alter the content of a file before upload with FileReader using javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, filereader

Is it possible to change the content of a file before beeing uploaded in javascript ? I can read the content but changing it seems impossible.

```
    f = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
        console.log(e.target)
        e.target.result = "new content"
        console.log(e.target);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to update FileList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078853/is-it-possible-to-update-filelist)

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite the value of a file input.

You can take the content of the file and send it with Ajax though.

```
reader.onload = function(e){
    const data = new FormData();
    const url = this.result;
    const blob = convertUrlToBlob(url);
    data.append("file_input", blob, "filename.ext");
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/example/url');
    xhr.send(data);
};
```

I won't go into the detail of how to write a `convertUrlToBlob` function, it is covered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata).

Comment: actually you can rewrite file input... [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078853/is-it-possible-to-update-filelist)]