# Front end base64/blob asset upload via form submission in CraftCMS3

Tags: craftcms

### Goal

I only have baes64/blob data available from a `<canvas />` and want to upload the image via from submission in front-end.

### Methods I've tried

I've read about [Uploading Files from Front-End Entry Forms](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#templating) in doc.

CraftCMS **ONLY** supports `<input type="file">`. **The file type input** does not support accepting re-assign value like other input tags directly.

Answer (score 1):

Assets fields do actually support submitting Base64-encoded data; it just wasn’t documented. [Done now though!](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/assets-fields.html#creating-new-assets)

Answer (score 0):

The file type input now support reassign value.
Steps:

1. convert your blob into file obj
2. Update your Filelist in js.
3. Updated Filelist replace with your input files.

   let file = new File([blob], fileName);
   let list = new DataTransfer();
   list.items.add(file);
   $(input)[0].files = myFileList;

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078853/is-it-possible-to-update-filelist) is original thread