# Froala editor, rename the file while upload

Tags: angular, wysiwyg, froala

Currently I'm using the froala editor with Angular and upload the file using AWS S3 service.

I want to rename the file before its upload to S3. So I use the event which is already present in froala, which is 'file.beforeUpload'

I'm getting the object as 'FileList'. With that I can't change the filename.

With that event I couldn't rename the file. Anyone help on this?

Comment: Have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078853/is-it-possible-to-update-filelist

Comment: I tried but it doesn't affect the image object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Actually froala editor itself appending the timestamp before the file name to avoid naming issue.*

You have two option on front-end as well as in back-end,

**Front-end:**

After getting the AWS hash key, you're setting the value like this,

```
this.options['imageUploadToS3'] = aws_hash_key;
```

before this, you can update the keyStart value by using the properties,

```
data.KeyStart = your_unique_name_come_here;
```

**Back-End:**

While getting the AWS hash key API itself you can set the unique name as start value, like this,

```
const configs = {
    bucket: 'stackOverflow',
    region: 'us2-west',
    keyStart: / + `your_unique_name_come_here`,
    acl: 'public-read',
    accessKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    secretKey: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  };
  return FroalaEditor.S3.getHash(configs);
```